# Joomla: categories do not count articles from sub-categories

Tags: joomla

I have Menu item "List All Categories". Problem, that categories do not count articles from sub-categories and shows 0, should count all articles from all subcategories.
I can not add picture, so I will describe:
Category (0)
 subcategory1 (1)
 subacategory2 (1)

I want, that Category will count articles from sub-categories (in example should be 2).

Is anybody knows, how to fix it?

Any help is very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.
EDIT:

I am using 2.5 Joomla. No, I do not writing component/plugin/module.
I am using menu item:List All Categories (Menus->Main Menu-> Add new menu item-> List All Categories).
At last, I found place, where this function is described.
here, **numitems** is digit of articles in categories:

```
 $subQuery = ' (SELECT cat.id as id FROM #__categories AS cat JOIN #__categories AS parent ' .
        'ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt WHERE parent.extension = ' . $db->quote($extension) .
        ' AND parent.published != 1 GROUP BY cat.id) ';
    $query->leftJoin($subQuery . 'AS badcats ON badcats.id = c.id');
    $query->where('badcats.id is null');

    // i for item
    if (isset($this->_options['countItems']) && $this->_options['countItems'] == 1)
    {
        if ($this->_options['published'] == 1)
        {
            $query->leftJoin(
                $db->quoteName($this->_table) . ' AS i ON i.' . $db->quoteName($this->_field) . ' = c.id AND i.' . $this->_statefield . ' = 1'
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $query->leftJoin($db->quoteName($this->_table) . ' AS i ON i.' . $db->quoteName($this->_field) . ' = c.id');
        }

        $query->select('COUNT(i.' . $db->quoteName($this->_key) . ') AS numitems');
    }
```

and from my understanding, there I need to create similar to $subQuery, but this time it should count articles from sub-categories. but I have no idea, how to do that ;/
Any ideas?

Comment: If you're writing a component/module/plugin for Joomla! you need to post relevant code so that we can help. You also need to tell us which version of Joomla!.

Comment: hello, I updated question. hope it helps.

Comment: Which version of Joomla! 2.5 are you using 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4 or 2.5.6?

Comment: 2.5.0 has massive security holes you really should upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla!'s List All Categories will only show the count for articles in that specific category a sub-category will not be counted in a parent category. This is because a parent category can have articles of it's own.

To show a total for all articles within a Category and it's sub-categories would require either modifying the Joomla core `com_content` component (any modification of core files should be considered bad) or creating a modified ***copy com_content component*** (which would be more efficient but probably more effort than you want) or creating a view override for the `categories` view.

Using the override will make the page display much heavier computation wise.

If you use an override all you will have  to do is:

1. copy `default_items.php` from `/components/com_content/views/categories/tmpl/default_items.php` to `/templates/your-template/html/com_content/categories/default_items.php` and
2. modify it to count the sub-items
3. modify it to display the total count

#### 2 - Count Sub-items

Insert this code after the `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` line:

```
// Calculate number of items including sub-categories using a recursive anonymous function
$countSubItems = function( $item ) use ( &$countSubItems ) {
    $children = $item->getChildren();
    if( count($children) == 0 ) {
        return $item->numitems;
    } else {
        $subItems = 0;
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $subItems += $countSubItems($child);
        }
        return $subItems = $item->numitems + $subItems;
    }
};
```

#### Call the count function

Insert the line to call the count function after the second `if` statement:

```
$allItemsInclSubCats = $countSubItems($item);
```

#### Display the total including sub-categories

Change the line that echo's the `$item->numitems;` to something like this:

```
<dd><?php echo $item->numitems; ?> ( <?php echo $allItemsInclSubCats; ?> including sub-categories )</dd>
```

Comment: Hello,
thank you for full explanation. however, it does not work.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for full explanation. however, it does not work.
please check how it looks:
http://tinypic.com/r/2ilc9s6/6
I have added 2 - Count Sub-items and Display the total including sub-categories in components/com_content/views/categories/tmpl/default_items.php as you advised.
what is $allItemsInclSubCats? where this variable is described?
I tried to write $countSubItems (gave error) and $subItems (remains same) instead $countSubItems. do you have any ideas? thank you in advance, you are very kind.

Comment: You have modified your core files this is **not** what I advised. See my edited answer I missed a line.

Comment: great, working like a charm! 
but I still want one thing. check picture with current situation:
http://i46.tinypic.com/2e58b4y.jpg
I want, that for parent categories shows only articles including sub-categories and for sub-categories shows only they own articles.
so I want it be:
Olandija (2)
  -Edinburgas(1)
  -Amsterdamas(1)
and so on.
what do you think, is possible somehow? 
OR another possibility to hide articles digit for parent categories and it can be:
Olandija(2)
  -Edinburgas 1 (1)
  -Amsterdamas 1 (1)
but first variant is better.
thank you very much

Comment: when I posted, I see it can be unclear. Olandija is parent category and Edinburgas and Amsterdamas is sub categories. Thanks.

Comment: he, I just hide echo $item->numitems;
and it shows as I need. so it is ok for now :)
one more time, thank you very much @cppl

Comment: if sub-categories has sub-categories too? how to count these articles?
I think, that 2 - Count Sub-items syntax
needed to change.
so parent category should count all articles (sub-categories, sub-sub- categories)
if you have any thoughts, let me know, thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @EdvaPtr - I'm glad it's working for you. Don't forget to accept the answer :D   
As for counting sub-categories the anonymous function that `$countSubItems` contains is recursive so it should count all items in all sub-categories no matter how deep.

Comment: yes, $countSubItems count all articles. it was my mistake, sorry.
I accept answer, I am new here and did not know, what to do.
thank you for your assistance :)