# Get the total number of items in a main category and all its subcategories (and levels)

Tags: mysql, joomla, subquery

I want to get the total number of items (articles) in a main category and all its subcategories.

Joomla determines this only for each category separately. Here is the generated DB query from Joomla 4 - menu type 'List All Categories in an Article Category Tree':

```
SELECT `c`.`id`,`c`.`asset_id`,`c`.`access`,`c`.`alias`,`c`.`checked_out`,`c`.`checked_out_time`,`c`.`created_time`,`c`.`created_user_id`,`c`.`description`,`c`.`extension`,`c`.`hits`,`c`.`language`,`c`.`level`,`c`.`lft`,`c`.`metadata`,`c`.`metadesc`,`c`.`metakey`,`c`.`modified_time`,`c`.`note`,`c`.`params`,`c`.`parent_id`,`c`.`path`,`c`.`published`,`c`.`rgt`,`c`.`title`,`c`.`modified_user_id`,`c`.`version`, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`c`.`alias`) != 0 THEN CONCAT_WS(':', `c`.`id`, `c`.`alias`) ELSE `c`.`id` END as `slug`,(
SELECT COUNT(`i`.`id`)
FROM `j40_content` AS `i`
WHERE `i`.`catid` = `c`.`id` AND `i`.`state` = 1) AS `numitems`
FROM `j40_categories` AS `c`
WHERE (`c`.`extension` = 'com_content' OR `c`.`extension` = 'system') AND `c`.`access` IN (1,5) AND `c`.`published` = 1
ORDER BY `c`.`lft`
```

The part with `numitems` contains the number of items for each category.

Example of a category structure:

```
- Main Category1
  -- Level 2 Category
    --- Level 3 Category
      ---- Level 4 Category
    --- Level 3 category 2
  -- Level 2 Category 2
- Main Category2
```

The number of levels is not limited!

I use a loop and read in the total for each category with an extra DB query. However, this is not very useful for a large number of categories and is too time-consuming. Therefore I am looking for a solution with one or two queries.

I found
[Joomla: categories do not count articles from sub-categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870022/joomla-categories-do-not-count-articles-from-sub-categories).
It is not exactly what I want to do, but the target was to reduce the DB queries and it accomplishes that.

What is a corresponding improvement of the original DB query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)